# Remove whitespaces from variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, routes

I have the following table in HTML and I want to remove all whitespaces from variable item.book.How can I do it?

```
<table>
        <theader>
          <tr>
            <th>Livro</th>
            <th>Autor da Review</th>
            <th>Review</th>
            <th>Link</th>
          </tr>
        </theader>
        <tbody>
          <% list.forEach((item,index)=>{ %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= item.book %></td>
              <td><%= item.name %></td>
              <td> <%= item.desc %></td>
              <td id="link"> <a href=/review/<%= item.email %>/ <%= item.book %>> /review/<%= item.email %>/<%= item.book %> </a></td>
            </tr>

            <% })%>
        </tbody>

      </table>
```

Comment: why don't you trim it in the server? can't change the code there?

Comment: @Ivan86 `list.forEach` is not ASP! maybe EJS

Comment: @balexandre in the server I store the name with spaces in a JSON File

Comment: @balexandre router.post("/submit", urlenCode, function (req, res, next) {
  const pathFile = path.resolve("public/JSON", "reviews.json");
  const dataRaw = fs.readFileSync(pathFile) || "[]";
  const dataProcessed = JSON.parse(dataRaw.toString());
  dataProcessed.push(req.body);
  fs.writeFileSync(pathFile, JSON.stringify(dataProcessed));
  res.render("submetido");
  console.log(pathFile);
});

Comment: @FábioPires don't post your code as a comment. Edit your question and add it up there

Comment: @FábioPires I would remove the `.toString()` seems that the `dataRaw` is already a string object, is it not? if not, do double... `dataProcessed = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( JSON.parse(dataRaw.toString()) ));` the function is quite fast and it's used when we also want to clone objects...